# how to get the index of observablecollection without a class property

Tags: windows-phone-7, loops

I simply want to get the index of a observablecollection, without actually setting a property in die Model which will represent the index.

I already have my observbalecollection (81 items), now I want to get the index of the item, but I am getting an invalid cast exception

```
   //loop deur die storyviewmodel en kry regte een, en set die itemssource
        for (int i = 0; i < App.StoryViewModel.story.Count; i++)
        {
            int collection_value = Convert.ToInt32(App.StoryViewModel.story[i]);
            if (collection_value == index)
            {
                news_source.Add(App.StoryViewModel.story[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                //nothing
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you convert values from the collection if you want to find the target value? What is the template parameter for your `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because story is a collection of objects other than ints.